# I can't power on VirtualBox virtual machines on Artix Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux

I installed VirtualBox (including the host modules packages, and I even loaded all of the modules for VirtualBox) on Artix Linux, when I tried to open-up a virtual machine, I got errors saying this

```
The virtual machine 'TestOS' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try    setting it up again by executing

 '/sbin/vboxconfig'

 as root.

 If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

#### My VirtualBox Packages

- `virtualbox-6.1.16-1`
- `virtualbox-host-modules-artix 6.1.16-2`
- `virtualbox-guest-iso 6.1.16-1`
- `virtualbox-guest-modules-artix 6.1.4-8`

When I tried to do the `/sbin/vboxconfig` command. I got this error message saying this.
`/sbin/vboxconfig: command not found`
 I tried using sudo, and I got this same exact message I just mentioned before.

I'll probably assume that I am using the incorrect VirtualBox modules version, but those are the latest packages on the Artix repository (I tried updating my Artix system too).

Comment: Odd. The only solution I have found online is to simply uninstall the VirtualBox you installed via package installer and install [VirtualBox via the official installers](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=99564).

Comment: How did you load the modules, _which_ modules did you load, and how did you check that they're in fact loaded? Do they show up in `lsmod`, and are any vbox devices created under `/dev`?

Comment: Okay, so I uninstalled, and reinstalled VirtualBox and the other three packages required to run it on my Artix system. I tried reloading the modules, but later I got a message saying<b>Unloading modules:  Loading modules: modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxnetadp not found in directory /lib/modules/5.9.1-artix1-1
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxnetflt not found in directory /lib/modules/5.9.1-artix1-1
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.9.1-artix1-1`

The VirtualBox modules don't show up in lsmod, and seems like no vbox devices are created under /dev.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same 'problem'. Enabling the vboxdrv module in the kernel made it work. Try to use

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

The kernel module should be available now. You can check that with

```
lsmod | grep vboxdrv
```

This should print one line containing name, size, and uses of the module like this

```
vboxdrv               528384  0
```